# Почему в .Net Framework есть Ajax и Ajax Helper, а в .Net Core нет?

Tags: c#, ajax, .net, asp.net-core

Хотел воспользоваться Ajax Helper-ами для отправки запросов, в интернете только о них и говорят. Подключаю jquery.validate.unobtrusive в проект и ничего не меняется. Нельзя использовать @using (Ajax... Использовать чистый Ajax мне просто не нравится, это как-то глупо в сравнении с тем, что есть у .Net framework. Как поступить, просто перейти на .net framework или можно как-то подключить ajax helperы или есть какая-то методичка по использованию jquery unobtrusive, т.к. понятной информации в интернете по Ajax под .net core совсем не нашел.

Comment: [Ajax helper tags documentation in Asp.net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50148838/312041)